# How to use plt.subplot for a table where the desired y axis are index values and desired X axis are feature names?

Tags: subplot, yaxis, x-axis

For example, I calculated a table as in the image. And I want to get 12 charts in the same area (4*3) So the first row will be for X, and the second row will be for y, third row for z and forth row for z.
The first column will be for the plot where I have fare ty (this year) shown together with fare diff (% difference) on the y axis and feature names as weeks on the x axis.
The second column will be for the plot where I have revenue ty (this year) shown together with revenue diff (% difference) on the y axis and feature names as same weeks on the x axis.
The third column will be for the plot where I have rev/mile diff (% difference) shown on the y axis and feature names as weeks on the x axis.
Trying something like this, but it does not work:

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (axs4, axs5, ax6), (ax7, ax8,ax9) ,(ax10, ax11,ax12) ) = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True,  figsize=(16, 10))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3),(0, 0))
ax1.plot(df['x fare th'], df.columns.values,  s=15)

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3),(0, 1))
ax2.bar(df['x rev th'], df.columns.values,  s=15)

.....

ax12 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3),(3, 3))
ax12.plot(df['t rev/mile diff'], df.columns.values,  s=15)

Can I use the df as it is to be able to get these plots? Do I have to convert my data frame into some other format to plot the charts? If, what is the necessary change for ddataframe?

Thank you in advance!

[Current Data frame to be used for plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKVUa.png)

I tried something like this:

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (axs4, axs5, ax6), (ax7, ax8,ax9) ,(ax10, ax11,ax12) ) = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True,  figsize=(16, 10))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3),(0, 0))
ax1.scatter(df['x fare th'], df.columns.values,  s=15)

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3),(0, 1))
ax2.scatter(df['x rev th'], df.columns.values,  s=15)

.....

ax12 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3),(3, 3))
ax12.scatter(df['t rev/mile diff'], df.columns.values,  s=15)

but it did not work.

And I want to see something like:

[Just plotting 12 charts in the same area with weeks on the X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOu3i.png)